# Install Canvas app managed package to Professional and Group edition

Tags: managed-package, profile, professional-edition, canvas, group-edition

I developed a canvas app that display a custom section in the account's page, so that I uses:

- canvas app
- virtualforce page
- page layout
- profiles (to assign which users can see the application)

I installed the app on the Enterprise edition as a managed package and it worked as expected, the problem is when I tried to install it on other editions I faced the following problems:

- in the Group edition the installation failed and it gives me a meaning less error message but mostly it can be installed because it includes component which is not supported.
- in the professional edition every thing works as expected but when it render the app it gives a permission error, and when I tried to allow the users throw profiles, I can't find a profiles link.

so my questions is:

1. **Can I install a managed package which include a canvas app into a Group Edition?**
2. **How can I manage the permissions to make the application works in the Professional Edition? can I include this permissions in the package? can I just allow all user form the beginning?**

thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Group and Professional have limitations](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm):

> Your app can contain business logic such as classes, triggers, email
>   services, etc. written in Apex. As a general rule, Apex is not
>   supported in GE/PE, so it will not run in these editions. However,
>   Apex developed as part of an ISV app and included in a managed package
>   can run in GE/PE, even though those editions do not support Apex by
>   default.

Also, [from Canvas documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connectpre/canvas_framework.pdf):

Group and Professional editions can only create apps with OAuth Access method unless profiles, page layouts, and the API have been enabled.

Comment: All what I need is to make all the user able to see the app, how come this can't be done?